# Is Ubuntu 22.04.1 already available?

Tags: 22.04

https://9to5linux.com/ubuntu-unity-22-04-1-released-with-the-latest-unity-7-6-desktop-environment suggests Ubuntu 22.04.1 is available for downloading on the offical website.
If I look at https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ I only see an image which is dated in april and not today.
Shoudl I still wait?
Or do I look somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

No, it's now scheduled for release on 11 August 2022.

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-1-delayed-until-august-11/29859

> tl;dr - A bug found in the 22.04.1 candidates will delay its release until 11 August so that we can fix the bug and retest the update. This bug does not exist in the current 22.04 image, and current users or installers of 22.04 are unaffected.

Ubuntu Unity Remix is **not** [a flavor of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours), thus isn't restricted to following the rules of Ubuntu *flavors*.